# Does this sequence exist?

Tags: number-theory

Can someone explain whether the following statement can be shown to be true and why?

There is no positive integer $r \geq 3$ for which there exists a sequence $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_r$ of nonzero integers with the property that:
$(b_1)^3+ (b_2)^3+\cdots+ (b_{r-1})^3=(b_r)^3$

Comment: As stated this is definitely false, for trivial reasons: $1^3+1^3+\dots+1^3=b_r^3$, $2015^3+(-2015)^3+12345^3+(-12345)^3+9^3=9^3$, and so on.

Comment: You just need to prove that $a^3+b^3=c^3$ has no solutions in the positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

The result is  true for $r=3$: Fermat's last theorem (proved for $r=3$ by Euler.)

For $r>3$ there are always non trivial solutions.

- $r=4$
  $$
  3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3.
  $$
- $r=5$
  $$
  11^3+12^3+13^3+14^3 = 20^3.
  $$
- $r=6$
  $$
  31^3+33^3+35^3+37^3+39^3+41^3 = 66^3.
  $$

Every sufficiently large integer is the sum of $7$ cubes, so there are solutions for $r\ge7$ (google Waring's problem.)